# Why does collection1 has the same values like collection2?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

## What I want

So I want to check 2 `ObservableCollections` if they equals each other.
If so, then return `Nothing Changed` (collection1 and collection2 are the same).
Otherwise return `Something Changed`.

## The Problem

The problem now is, that both collection contains the same values even when I change items from collection 2.

I posted some Code and `gif` of the Debug result to show you what I get.
I dont understand, why both Collections are the same after clicking the Save Button.

## Code

**ViewModel**

In my ViewModel I have:
1 `ObservableCollection` called `RightsCollection`.
This should contain the rights on my XAML which I can change via `ToggleButton`.

1 `Employee` class where a `ObservableCollection<Groups>` is located and inside of the `Groups.Col` there is a `ObservableCollection<Rights>` which contains the default group rights which was loaded from DataBase which cant be changed.

Note: My `get` `set` is always the same. They just have other names and DataTypes consider to its field datatype.

```
private Employee _singleEmployee = new Employee();
public Employee SingleEmployee
{
    get => _singleEmployee;
    set
    {
        if (_singleEmployee == value) return;
        _singleEmployee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SingleEmployee");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Groups> _groupsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Groups>();
// public get set GroupsCollection (same like first).

private ObservableCollection<Rights> _rightsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Rights>();
// public get set RightsCollection (same like first).
```

**Employee Class**

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _employeeId;
    private string _firstName;
    private Groups _group = new Group();

    // public get set EmployeeId (Same like first).
    // public get set Group (same like first).
}
```

**Rights Class**

```
private int _rightId;
private string _rightName;
private bool _hasRight;

// Again get set is same
```

**Groups Class**

```
private int _groupId;
private string _groupName;
private ObservableCollection<Rights> _rights;

// Again, same Get/Set like always
```

**XAML**

In my XAML I have:
a `ComboBox`. `ComboBox.ItemsSource` bind to `GroupsCollection`. `ComboBox.SelectedValue` bind to `SingleEmployee.Group`.

So while changing the ComboBox, the Group of the Single Employee will be set.

This `ComboBox` also got an `SelectionChanged` Event where I set the `RightsCollection` equal to `SingleEmployee.Group.Rights`. So that both contains the same items/values now.

It also contains an `ItemsControl` where I can set the rights myself (and where the rights will be loaded when `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` (which works).

```
<ComboBox x:Name="GroupComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding SingleEmployee.Group}" DisplayMemberPath="GroupName" SelectionChanged="GroupComboBox_SelectionChanged">
```

ItemsControl

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RightsCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <ToggleButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10" IsChecked="{Binding HasRight}"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding RightName}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10" />
                </DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RightsDesc}" Margin="30 0 0 10" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**SelectionChanged Event in Code-Behind**

```
Debug.WriteLine("############ SelectionChanged Event ############");
Debug.WriteLine("# Before Change ##");
Debug.WriteLine($"SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count} | RightsCollection.Count: {_viewModel.RightsCollection.Count}");
for (int i = 0; i < _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].RightName}, HasRight: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].HasRight} || Name: {_viewModel.RightsCollection[i].RightName}, HasRight: {_viewModel.RightsCollection[i].HasRight}");
}

_viewModel.RightsCollection = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights;

Debug.WriteLine("# After Change #");
Debug.WriteLine($"SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count} | RightsCollection.Count: {_viewModel.RightsCollection.Count}");
for (int i = 0; i < _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine$"Name: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].RightName}, HasRight: {_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].HasRight} || Name: {_viewModel.RightsCollection[i].RightName}, HasRight: {_viewModel.RightsCollection[i].HasRight}");
}

Debug.WriteLine("########## SelectionChanged Event END ##########");
Debug.WriteLine("################################################");
```

**Set ViewModel in Code-Behind**

```
private readonly EmployeeViewModel _viewModel;

// constructor...
{
_viewModel = (EmployeeViewModel) DataContext;
}
```

**Save Button Command Method**

```
Debug.WriteLine("############## After Button Click ##############");
for (int i = 0; i < RightsCollection.Count; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].RightName}, HasRight: {SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].HasRight} || Name: {RightsCollection[i].RightName}, HasRight: {RightsCollection[i].HasRight}");
}
Debug.WriteLine("################################################");

bool equal = RightsCollection.Count == SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count && RightsCollection.All(x => SSingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Contains(x));

Debug.WriteLine(equal ? "Nothing Changed" : "Something changed");
```

## What I tried

**SelectionChanged Event**

```
// No Success
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Rights>(_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights);
_viewModel.RightsCollection = collection;
```

.

```
// No Success
foreach(var item in _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights)
    _viewModel.RightsCollection.Add(item);
```

## Result of the Debugging

SelectionChangedResult
[image: SelectionChangedResult (GIF)] |

SelectionChangedResult 
[image: SelectionChangedResult (Picture)]

After Button Click
[image: After Button Click (GIF)]

After Button Click
[image: After Button Click (Picture)]

Answer (score 2):

```
_viewModel.RightsCollection = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights;
```

the left collection has the same reference of the right collection. 
So, if you change one collection it will reflect in the other collection.

```
ObservableCollection<Whatever> _viewModel.RightsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Whatever>();

foreach(var item in _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights)
    _viewModel.RightsCollection.Add(item);
```

Comment: Oh okay. So I need to delete all items from `RightsCollection` in `SelectionChanged Event` and add items from `SingleEmployee.Group.Rights` to the `RightsCollection` through a foreach ?

Comment: What I wrote didn't worked. `_viewModel.RightsCollection.Clear(); foreach (var item in _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights)
            {
                _viewModel.RightsCollection.Add(item);
            }`

Comment: yes, if u just want to compare the collections, not the items inside it

Comment: The thing is, that with this `foreach` my Debug Save Button returns the same result like before (both Collections contains the same items).

Comment: Are u doing this?
 `_viewModel.RightsCollection = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights;`

Comment: No, i deleted this line.

Comment: The function to check if the has changed works when you delete one element of the collection, but doesnt work when u make changes in the element right?

Comment: Im not deleting elemens of the collection. I only change the `.HasRight` Property.

Comment: Its the same problem. You have the same elements in both collections, if you chage you element in one collection it will reflect in same element in the other collection

Comment: But how I can prevent reflectation?

Comment: When you are adding to the list you must instance a new Right and copy the properties of the original. Then you can compare the objects in the list overloading the operator ==.

`foreach(Right item in _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights)`
    `RightsCollection.Any(x => x == item) `

Comment: so instead of `_viewModel.RightsCollection = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights;` i create a new local collection based on `Group.Rights` Collection and set this collection to `RightsCollection` ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in my `SelectionChanged Event` deleting this line:

```
_viewModel.RightsCollection = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights;
```

and replaced it with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count; i++)
{
    if (_viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].HasRight != _viewModel.RightsCollection[i].HasRight)
    {
        _viewModel.RightsCollection[i].HasRight = _viewModel.SingleEmployee.Group.Rights[i].HasRight;
    }
}
```

Because both collections are nearly the same, they will always have the same amount of items so I can use a `for`-loop.
If a value is not the same, then the value will change.

This way I don't create a reflection (I guess) so it's working.

The only thing now is, that

```
bool equal = RightsCollection.Count == SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Count && RightsCollection.All(x => SingleEmployee.Group.Rights.Contains(x));
```

isn't working but I will use a for-loop here too which checks if the items contains the same value, if not then `"Something changed"`.